# What is wrong with my ETrade OAuth get token request?

Tags: perl, command-line, oauth, wget, etrade-api

The server is responding with a less than helpful message.

> Unable to get a request token: Request for https://etwssandbox.etrade.com/oauth/sandbox/request_token?oauth_callback=oob&oauth_consumer_key=aaf0812a4bcc6e4c21783af47cf88237&oauth_nonce=3495463522&oauth_signature=ykqRaZc18GwIoqHtYqtxzsMq4xs%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1371092839&oauth_version=1.0 failed,HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

```
Connection: close
Content-Length: 62
Client-Date: Thu, 13 Jun 2013 03:07:19 GMT
Client-Peer: 12.153.224.230:443
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /C=US/O=VeriSign, Inc./OU=VeriSign Trust Network/OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10/CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /C=US/ST=New York/L=New York/O=ETRADE FINANCIAL CORPORATION/OU=Global Information Security/CN=etwssandbox.etrade.com
Client-SSL-Cipher: RC4-MD5

<html><body><b>Http/1.1 400 Bad Request</b></body> </html>
```

### OK I will try with headers. All required parameters are present.

> $ wget -d -O- --header='Authorization: OAuth realm="",oauth_callback="oob",oauth_consumer_key="aaf0812a4bcc6e4c21783af47cf88237",oauth_nonce="3495463522",oauth_signature="ykqRaZc18GwIoqHtYqtxzsMq4xs%3D",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1371092839",oauth_version="1.0"' 'https://etwssandbox.etrade.com/oauth/sandbox/request_token'

```
Setting --output-document (outputdocument) to -
Setting --header (header) to Authorization: OAuth realm="",oauth_callback="oob",oauth_consumer_key="aaf0812a4bcc6e4c21783af47cf88237",oauth_nonce="3495463522",oauth_signature="ykqRaZc18GwIoqHtYqtxzsMq4xs%3D",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1371092839"
DEBUG output created by Wget 1.13.4 on cygwin.

URI encoding = `UTF-8'
--2013-06-12 23:08:33--  https://etwssandbox.etrade.com/oauth/sandbox/request_token
Resolving etwssandbox.etrade.com (etwssandbox.etrade.com)... 12.153.224.230, 198.93.34.230
Caching etwssandbox.etrade.com => 12.153.224.230 198.93.34.230
Connecting to etwssandbox.etrade.com (etwssandbox.etrade.com)|12.153.224.230|:443... connected.
Created socket 3.
Releasing 0x80733128 (new refcount 1).

---request begin---
GET /oauth/sandbox/request_token HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: Wget/1.13.4 (cygwin)
Accept: */*
Host: etwssandbox.etrade.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
Authorization: OAuth realm="",oauth_callback="oob",oauth_consumer_key="aaf0812a4bcc6e4c21783af47cf88237",oauth_nonce="3495463522",oauth_signature="ykqRaZc18GwIoqHtYqtxzsMq4xs%3D",oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1",oauth_timestamp="1371092839"

---request end---
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
---response begin---
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-Length:62
Connection: close

---response end---
400 Bad Request
2013-06-12 23:08:34 ERROR 400: Bad Request.
```

#### That still did not work. Let me verify the signature. Notice my key and secret are correct.

#### First URL encode all the parameters to form a base string for signing.

> $ perl -MURI::Escape -e "print uri_escape('oauth_callback=oob&oauth_consumer_key=aaf0812a4bcc6e4c21783af47cf88237&oauth_nonce=3495463522&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1371092839&oauth_version=1.0')"
>
> oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%3Daaf0812a4bcc6e4c21783af47cf88237%26oauth_nonce%3D3495463522%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1371092839%26oauth_version%3D1.0

#### Now hash with HMAC-SHA1, encode with Base64 (no newline at end), and URL encode the resulting signature.

#### There is an ampersand at the end of the consumer secret because we don't have a token secret yet (it is empty).

> $ perl -MDigest::HMAC_SHA1=hmac_sha1 -MMIME::Base64 -MURI::Escape -e "print uri_escape(encode_base64(hmac_sha1('GET&https%3A%2F%2Fetwssandbox.etrade.com%2Foauth%2Fsandbox%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Doob%26oauth_consumer_key%3Daaf0812a4bcc6e4c21783af47cf88237%26oauth_nonce%3D3495463522%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1371092839%26oauth_version%3D1.0', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&'), ''))"

```
ykqRaZc18GwIoqHtYqtxzsMq4xs%3D
```

#### This signature matches the above.

The specs are here: http://oauth.net/core/1.0a/#signing_process

ETrade specs are here: https://us.etrade.com/ctnt/dev-portal/getDetail?contentUri=V0_Documentation-AuthorizationAPI-GetRequestToken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ETrade's documentation is broken. They specify in the Sandbox environment uses different hosts and URLs

https://us.etrade.com/ctnt/dev-portal/getContent?contentUri=V0_Documentation-DeveloperGuides-Sandbox

but for OAuth they do not. That part is never mentioned and I had to look in the source code for one of their SDKs to find out.

```
|Environment| URL |
|Production |https://etws.etrade.com/{module}/rest/{API}  |
|Sandbox    |https://etwssandbox.etrade.com/{module}/sandbox/rest/{API} |
```

Comment: OMG... thank you thank you!
I looked at my code numerous times, and I can't seem to figure out what was wrong! They really should clarify that in their documentation.

Comment: This answer needs updated with modern URLs for Etrade APIs.